# UICollectionView- How to remove spacing above first cell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

UICollectionView- How to remove spacing above first cell?

I have the top inset = 0, and lines = 10

[image]

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.width, 44);
}
return CGSizeMake(300, 150);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

Seems it is something to do with setting the first cell to a different size

if i remove the check for row ==0 in sizeForItemAtIndexPath and return same for all cells it is flush with the top.

Any ideas?

Comment: which is your first cell Lable or bar displaying there

Answer (score 11):

Solution is just to write inside `viewDidLoad`

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 8):

I did it following way (tested on iOS7, **55** is a magic value):

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //-55 is a tweak value to remove top spacing
    return CGSizeMake(1, -55);
}
```

Alternative way using your code:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(-55, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: 55 begins the content about 45 above the top of the screen.

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to use Interface Builder, you can uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets" on the View Controller's Attribute Inspector:

[image: Uncheck here.]

Or use Amit's answer to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so that one is your top inset. Edit your question with some piece of code you have applied.

If it was collectionView inset then it should remove by passing 0 as top inset.

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

And the following layout delegate used for row spacing.

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using srtuct and spring set the collectionview autoresizing mask like this and also make sure you set the frame y to 0

[image]